# Laravel: Route Model Binding and Namespace

Tags: model, laravel-4, routes, namespaces

I am successfully using the following codes to auto-route HTTP parameters to a model in Laravel:

```
Route::model('user', 'User', function()
{
    throw new AccountNotFoundException('Account does not exists.');
});
```

I recently started using namespaces to my classes and that's where the problem started.

So far, I tried this one to no avail:

```
Route::model('user', 'PackageName\User\Repository\User', ....blahh....)
```

Question: How do I specify the namespace on Model routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the error message itself, I chanced to solve the problem. Apparently the 2nd parameter of the Route::model() method accepts either a string class name or an object of the model itself:

```
Route::model('user', new PackageName\User\Repository\User, function()
{
    throw new AccountNotFoundException('Account does not exists.');
});
```

where:

```
new PackageName\User\Repository\User
```

is an instantiation of the namespaced model.